# How to vertically center a span/svg inside a div

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6yfv3u5m/

HTML:

```
<div id="dvMore">
    <div id="dvMore2">
        <span id="spMore">View More</span>
        <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't have a height, just dynamic content.

Edit: Tried to set dvMore2 to `vertically-align: center`. Also tried to add a placeholder span and set the vertical-align to center but none of them worked.

Answer (score 4):

Add `display: flex;` `align-items: center;`

https://jsfiddle.net/6yfv3u5m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `vertical-align` property like below. You need to set it on the children, not the parent itself:

```css
#dvMore2 * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="dvMore">
  <div id="dvMore2">
    <span id="spMore">View More</span>
    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```